# How to update database by ant (versioning)?

Tags: database, ant, versioning

I have a web application on java, which is working with database. I need an ant’s script that will deploy or update my application to latest version. There is no problem with application part, but I don't know how to do database update.

I have an idea to build-in some meta-information (number of version) to the names of sql scripts.

For example:

- DB_1.0.0.sql
- DB_1.0.1.sql
- DB_1.2.0.sql
- DB_2.0.0.sql
- DB_2.1.0.sql

My script detected, that current version was 1.0.1, so I need to execute DB_1.2.0.sql, DB_2.0.0.sql, DB_2.1.0.sql files by SQL task. Problem is: how to find files with ant, that I need to execute.

Maybe it is not the best way to update database. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/ant) works as you've described. It keeps a record of the SQL files already applied to the  database, enabling an automatic upgrade. Simple and straight forward to use.

A more powerful solution, IMHO, is [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/index.html). It has an XML syntax to record database changes, enabling the generation of cross-platform SQL. It also has some powerful features such as the ability to roll-back changes and perform diff's between databases.

Comment: @MarkOConnor Thank you for your answer! I apologize that i've not replied for a long time. Flyway looks like I need.

Comment: 404 on your second link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your filenames follow a strict convetion. In that case you can find files   by matching a pattern [filelist](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) and execute using [sql](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html).

You can use  [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/)  to write some tasks that can help in database schema updates-