# flyway: sql*plus specific command's execution

Tags: oracle, ant, versioning, sqlplus, flyway

When I am trying to execute my sql script by Flyway, I get **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900** on line: **@@some_dir/run.sql**.

Of course, this is specific sql*plus command. Is there some way to execute this command by Flyway? If there is not, how I can execute my script by Ant and how I can do [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075385/how-to-update-database-by-ant-versioning) without Flyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for this.

One solution might be to refactor your sql files, to have this file run as a regular migration instead.